# Loading Data from Bundled Realm Database in Swift

Tags: swift, realm, mapbox

I’m relatively new to Realm. My task is to bundle a RealmDB and make it writable. Thus far I have copied the bundled realm file into the project and implemented the following code in the app delegate. Above the "func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions” I used the following function:

```
func bundleURL(name: String) -> NSURL? {
  return NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("data", withExtension: "realm") }
```

And below didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I used the following:

```
if let v0URL = bundleURL("data.realm") {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(defaultURL)
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(v0URL, toURL: defaultURL)
        } catch {}
```

The issue is that I have to load the app twice to get the data to show up in a MapViewController, which is the first controller upon launch. In this case, I want map pins in the MapViewController to automatically appear upon build. I tried to implement a notification in the MapViewController using the following:

```
let results = try! Realm().objects(Spaces)
notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock {[weak self](changes: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Sapces>>) in 
self!.populateMap()
```

I also tried to implement a Database Manager:

```
func getDBItems() -> [Spaces] {
 let dbItemsFromRealm  = try! Realm().objects(Spaces)
    var bathroom = [Spaces]()

    if dbItemsFromRealm.count > 0 {
        for dbItemsInRealm in dbItemsFromRealm {
            let spaces = dbItemsInRealm as Spaces
            space.append(space)
        }
    }
    return space
}
```

}

However, I can’t get the pins to load upon launch. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is what I'd expect to see if you've already opened the Realm at the target path prior to copying the bundled Realm over to that location. You can confirm this by putting a breakpoint on the `Realm` initializer and on your code that calls `removeItemAtURL` and seeing which is hit first.

Comment: I can't find a good Swift tutorial for bundling a writeable Realm into an Xcode bundle; could you point us to one?